# Dates not casting after upgrading to Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have just upgraded from Laravel 6 (PHP 7.4) to Laravel 7 (PHP 7.4) and casting dates in a model has completely stopped working.

For example, in my User model, I have the following `$dates` array:

```
protected $dates = [
    'online_at'
];
```

The following is returned: `2020-08-17T00:00:00.000000Z` yet I am expecting a Carbon object to be returned.

The field in the MySQL database is DATETIME.

The same is happening with the `created_at`, `updated_at`, and `deleted_at` fields. It's also the same across all models.

I have tried moving the field into the `$casts` array but I get the same result.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is happening only for API?

Comment: Just tested that, and yes that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Laravel 7** uses a new date serialization format when using the **toArray** or **toJson** method on Eloquent models.

Previously, dates would be serialized to a format like the following :

```
2019-12-02 20:01:00
```

Dates serialized using the **ISO-8601** format will appear like :

```
2019-12-02T20:01:00.283041Z
```

Please note that **ISO-8601** dates are always expressed in **UTC**.

If you would like to keep using the previous behavior you can override the `serializeDate()` method on your model :

```
use DateTimeInterface;

protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

See the official upgrade doc  [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization)