# Laravel get data by time

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get data that has been created from 10 minutes ago till now but it returns wrong results

```
$defs = OrderDefaultProgress::where('name', 'Laundry Mencari supir')->pluck('id')->toArray();
$progresses = OrderProgress::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(10))->whereIn('progress_id', $defs)->get();
```

`$progresses` return data with time stamp of `2021-02-07T09:15:44.000000Z` while this data is belong to 8 hours ago.

```
[
    {
        "id": "7ce3bd58-3f19-4de9-8b92-e196d6e7b97f",
        "order_id": "175fe9ed-6932-4d5e-ba8f-ec36acf7d872",
        "progress_id": "b816f3bf-9c58-4e77-8d67-b834cac4ae77",
        "created_at": "2021-02-07T09:15:44.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-07T09:15:44.000000Z"
    }
]
```

Strange thing is that in my database I don't even have such timestamp!

[image: one]

Comment: Laravel 7 uses a new date serialization format when using the toArray or toJson method on Eloquent models. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63448356/4575350

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use from 'where' in here, use from `whereBetween` inested of `where` like:

```
OrderProgress::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->subMinutes(10), Carbon::now()])->whereIn('progress_id', $defs)->get();
```

I hope this work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Need use code like this

```
$progresses = OrderProgress::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(10))->whereIn('progress_id', $defs)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `whereDate` method

```
OrderProgress::whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(10))
->whereIn('progress_id', $defs)->get();
```

Comment: If `created_at` is indexed then resultant query will ignore that index.  Reference [sargable queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)