# Laravel why my User model is automatically converting unix timestamp to datetime string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need my api to output all dates as seconds since epoch, however when I call my /user route this is what I get:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "jk",
"email": "*****@*****",
"email_verified_at": 1619606859,
"can_add": 1,
"ip_registered": "*****",
"created_at": "2021-04-28T10:46:50.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-04-28T10:47:39.000000Z"
}
```

Here is my User model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'can_add',
        'ip_registered',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];


    protected $dateFormat = 'U';
}
```

As you can see, I set dateFormat to 'U'.

Here is my users table migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->unsignedInteger('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->boolean('can_add');
            $table->string('ip_registered');
            $table->unsignedInteger('created_at');
            $table->unsignedInteger('updated_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

As you can see, created_at and updated_at are integers, not timestamps.

And finally here is the controller function that is responsible for handling the request:

```
public function user(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json(User::find(Auth::id()));
}
```

Why is laravel automatically converting updated_at and created_at, but not converting email_verified_at, and how to stop it from converting anything at all?

EDIT:
In case somebody has the same problem, here is my exact solution:

```
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return (int)$date->format('U');
}
```

Comment: By default, both created_at and updated_at are casts as $dates of Eloquent model so you can perform Carbon operations on them, without converting to Carbon instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dates not casting after upgrading to Laravel 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448198/dates-not-casting-after-upgrading-to-laravel-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Laravel 7, they have changed the date serialization to Carbon's `toJson` method as stated in their [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization). To revert it, add a `serializeDate` method to your models.

```php
use DateTimeInterface;

/**
 * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
 *
 * @param  \DateTimeInterface  $date
 * @return string
 */
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```