# Laravel 8 - Date Casting

Tags: laravel, date, casting, laravel-8, php-carbon

I'm confused using *Date Casting* (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting) in Laravel 8.

I need to *get*, from DB, all my *date* fields with format `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP`; for example: `1990-02-12T01:08:12.820+00:00`.

To do that, in my `Origin` Model, I set:

```
class Origin extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'myDate' => 'datetime:Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP'
    ];
}
```

Now, the field `myDate` is casted to `Carbon`:

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>>
>>> $origin = App\Origin::first();
>>>
>>> dd($origin->myDate);
Illuminate\Support\Carbon @634784892^ {#4629
  #constructedObjectId: "000000005620d556000000007f71416e"
  #localMonthsOverflow: null
  #localYearsOverflow: null
  #localStrictModeEnabled: null
  #localHumanDiffOptions: null
  #localToStringFormat: null
  #localSerializer: null
  #localMacros: null
  #localGenericMacros: null
  #localFormatFunction: null
  #localTranslator: null
  #dumpProperties: array:3 [
    0 => "date"
    1 => "timezone_type"
    2 => "timezone"
  ]
  #dumpLocale: null
  date: 1990-02-12 01:08:12.820 UTC (+00:00)
}
>>>
>>>
```

but when I get the attribute, the output doesn't respect the format `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP`:

```
>>>
>>> echo $origin->myDate;
1990-02-12 01:08:12⏎
>>>
>>>
```

to obtain the required format, I need to format It again:

```
>>>
>>> echo $origin->myDate->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP');
1990-02-12T01:08:12.820+00:00⏎
>>>
>>>
```

or convert the Model `toArray()` before using it:

```
>>>
>>> echo $origin->toArray()['myDate'];
1990-02-12T01:08:12.820+00:00⏎
>>>
>>>
```

---

What is the best practice the set the *date format* and get the correct output? I'd like to use:

```
>>>
>>> echo $origin->myDate;
1990-02-12T01:08:12.820+00:00⏎
>>>
>>>
```

Thank you

Comment: what format you need ?

Comment: `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP`

Comment: so laravel cast is not working ? for u

Comment: As you can see above, the `echo $origin->myDate` returns `1990-02-12 01:08:12` instead of `1990-02-12T01:08:12.820+00:00`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dates not casting after upgrading to Laravel 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448198/dates-not-casting-after-upgrading-to-laravel-7)

Answer (score 1):

as your saying laravel casting format is not working you can create accessor like this

```php
class Origin extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'myDate' => 'datetime:Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP'
    ];


    public function getMyDateAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP');
    }
}
```

it will make sure you will always return this format

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: Ok, I tried It and It works; but I'd like to understand why `$casts` doesn't work. Is a my error?

Comment: Possible answer: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32335